# How to use last will and testament with device client?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I'm using the DeviceClient from the official Azure IoT SDK to connect to an IoT Hub from a customer. The configured protocoll is MQTT. Now I got a new requirement to implement a last will and testamant (LWT) message. I know this MQTT feature and how it would work with a native MQTT client. But how can I use this with the DeviceClient? Or do I need to switch to a native MQTT client (which would cause a lot of rework)?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out how to do this:

```
MqttTransportSettings mqttSettings = new MqttTransportSettings(TransportType.Mqtt_Tcp_Only);
mqttSettings.KeepAliveInSeconds = 60; // Or whatever you like
mqttSettings.WillMessage = new WillMessage(QualityOfService.AtLeastOnce, will); // will is a normal Message instance
mqttSettings.HasWill = true;

this.client = DeviceClient.Create(this.eiotHost, authentication, new ITransportSettings[] { mqttSettings });
```

It is important to set also the HasWill property and not only the WillMessage!